# Sending a GET request to another domain using jQuery, http response not required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to send a GET request to another domain preferably using jQuery. This isn't a same origin policy bypass because I don't need to get a response.  For instance using JavaScript I know I can do this:

```
document.write('<img src="http://somedomain.com/someapp.php?data='+data+'>')
```

Is there a better way using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the `<img>` element but do nothing with it...it'll cause an immediate fetch, resulting in a GET request:

```
$('<img src="http://somedomain.com/someapp.php?data='+data+'">');
```

Comment: You sir are a ninja of high Fortitude and Wisdom.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you don't need it in the DOM, so you could do this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://somedomain.com/someapp.php...' + ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach script tags to the DOM using JS.

```
var scrElem=document.createElement("script");
scrElem.type="text/javascript"; //maybe not required
scrElem.src="http://bla";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scrElem);
```

If you want to be really tidy about it, you could also give the script element an `id` attribute so you can remove it when it's done its job.

Alternatively, jQuery [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) wraps all this up nicely.

Comment: `getScript` won't work because it may throw an error the response may not be valid javascript -- even if he doesn't need the response it will still try to parse it.

Comment: although it sounds like OP is probably in charge at "other domain", so can craft response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, add it to the <head> element. I'm not sure if it works in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 $('selector').append('<img width="0" height="0" src="http://somedomain.com/someapp.php?data=' + encodeURIComponent(data) + '>');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to inject the `<img>` into the DOM.

Simply:

```
var request=$('<img/>').attr('src','http://somedomain.com/someapp.php?data='+data);
```

This will create a new img-Element, similar to new Image() .
If there is a src-attribute provided, the image will be  loaded(the request sended)

But I think it's not a better way, I's another way.
It,s the jQuery-way to do Martin's Proposal.

However, it would be good if the requested ressource didn't produce large response, because the response will be loaded anyway.